# Get values from 2d array to list with row an column position

Tags: python, numpy

I have an 2D array (source: csv file) like this (with empty values, size = approx. 5000rows x 5000cols):

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[11,12,13,14,15,,17,18,19,20]
[21,22,,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
```

Now I want a list from all values in the style [rowposition,columposition,value]

```
1,1,0
1,2,1
1,3,2
1,4,3
1,5,4
1,6,5
[..]
3,1,21
3,2,22
3,3,
3,4,24
[...]
```

(I know it counts from 0, instead 1 but maybe we can work around that?)

I don't know much about python unfortunately, i only have a clumsy 2d matrix :D
But what I see is Python und Numpy the best thing for such a task?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]])

y = np.hstack([np.argwhere(x==x), x.ravel().reshape(-1,1)])
```

Outputs:

```py
[[ 0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  1]
 [ 0  2  2]
 [ 0  3  3]
 [ 0  4  4]
 [ 0  5  5]
 [ 0  6  6]
 [ 0  7  7]
 [ 0  8  8]
 [ 0  9  9]
 [ 1  0 11]
 [ 1  1 12]
 [ 1  2 13]
 [ 1  3 14]
 [ 1  4 15]
 [ 1  5 16]
 [ 1  6 17]
 [ 1  7 18]
 [ 1  8 19]
 [ 1  9 20]
 [ 2  0 21]
 [ 2  1 22]
 [ 2  2 23]
 [ 2  3 24]
 [ 2  4 25]
 [ 2  5 26]
 [ 2  6 27]
 [ 2  7 28]
 [ 2  8 29]
 [ 2  9 30]]
```

`np.argwhere(x==x)` returns all the coordinates of records matching the condition (which is all of them), flattened in row-wise order. `x.ravel()` is analogically flattening row-wise (the rest is just to stick these 2 together).